# Is there the opposite way of creating blocks of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array whose shape is (4,4) and I divided him for blocks with (2,2), can I have the opposite way to get the (4,4) shape again?

Example :

```
array_4x4 = [[100,123,3,7],
         [134,43,67,90],
         [9,10,11,12],
         [13,14,15,16]]

blocks_2x2 = [[100,123,134,43],[3,7,67,90],[9,10,13,14],[11,12,15,16]]
```

How could I get the first shape again?

```
blocks_2x2 = [[100,123,134,43],[3,7,67,90],[9,10,13,14],[11,12,15,16]]
num_blocks = 4
final_ = []
for i in range(num_blocks):
   for j in range(2):
       final_.append(np.array(blocks_2x2 [i])[:,j])
```

How could I do that?

Comment: can show us expected output?

Comment: its the list array_4x4 .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using `numpy`, as following:

```
blocks_2x2 = [[1,2,5,6],[3,4,7,8],[9,10,13,14],[11,12,15,16]]

result = []
for i in range(0,len(blocks_2x2)-1,2):
    for j in range(2):
        result.append(blocks_2x2[i][j*2:j*2+2] + blocks_2x2[i+1][j*2:j*2+2])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

We iterate every two sublists in the `blocks_2x2` list and we join each first and second half of the two lists. Note that the specific code was only tested for the data you provided.

Comment: that isnt generic

Comment: the values could be random

Comment: Could you provide an example or maybe explain what you mean by _random_?